# Run code continuously online to update my firebase for my flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an app that communicates with a soccer API ,I don't want my data to be updated only when the user is using my app but I want to run code continuously online separately and get data from the soccer APIs , process it  and update my firebase database so the users find already processed data, I did some research and found Cloud functions but that requires an event to trigger if I am not mistaken , I am new to this so forgive me if the answer is obvious, I need something that doesn't need to be triggered but will be running and updating data, is there a way to achieve this with my flutter app, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scheduled functions in cloud functions, and it costs only $0.10 per month for the schedule trigger. Notice per month, in total, not 10 cents for every time it runs.

You can schedule it to run whenever you want, and after the data is written to your firestore database, you can use that as a trigger, which makes sense.